# Primefaces 6.0 dialog not showing from ui:composition

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using Primefaces 6.0, jsf 2.2 and tomcat 9. I have a dialog box within a ui:composition which does not show up but it happens to show up when i place it in the template file.

Below is the code for the template:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
            <title>Title</title>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                App Name
            </p:layoutUnit>


            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="250" collapsible="true">
                <p:menu toggleable="true">
                    <p:submenu label="Setups">
                        <p:menuitem value="Department" url="/dept" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Company Clients" url="/companies"  icon="ui-icon-contact" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Products" url="/products" icon="ui-icon-heart" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Doctors" url="/doctors" icon="ui-icon-person" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Suppliers" url="/suppliers" icon="ui-icon-close" />

                        <p:menuitem value="Settings" url="/settings" />
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:submenu label="Kenko">
                        <p:menuitem value="Patient Data" url="/patientdata" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Point Of Sale" url="/pos"  icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Company Medicals" url="/companymedicals"  />
                        <p:menuitem value="Reports" url="/reports" icon="ui-icon-home" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Consultation" url="/consultation" icon="ui-icon-close" />

                        <p:menuitem value="Settings" url="/settings" />
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:submenu label="User Management">
                        <p:menuitem value="List Of Users" url="/users"  icon="ui-icon-star"  />
                        <p:menuitem value="Add Users" url="/users"  icon="ui-icon-star" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Modify Permissions" url="/users"  icon="ui-icon-star" />
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menu>

            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <ui:insert name="content">WELCOME</ui:insert>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Footer
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>

    </h:body>

</f:view>
```

and below is also the code for the facelet:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/views/template/layout.xhtml"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<ui:define name="content">
    <p:commandButton value="Add New User" icon="ui-icon-extlink" onclick="PF('addUserModal').show();"  />
    <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{usersList}">
        <p:column headerText="Full Name">
            #{user.get("fullName")}
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="User Name">
            #{user.get("username")}
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="E-Mail">
            #{user.get("email")}
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Privileges">
            #{user.get("privilege")}
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Department">
            #{user.get("department")}
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Phone Number">
            #{user.get("phoneNumber")}
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</ui:define>

<p:dialog header="Add New User" id="addUserModal" widgetVar="addUserModal" height="300">
        <h:inputText value="fullName" />
        <h:inputText value="fullName" />
        <h:inputText value="fullName" />
        <h:inputText value="fullName" />
        <h:inputText value="fullName" />
        <h:inputText value="fullName" />
        <h:inputText value="fullName" />
        <h:inputText value="fullName" />
</p:dialog>
```

I keep getting the error: `TypeError: PF(...) is undefined` and I've done a lot search but none seems to help me with my problem.

I really need someone to help me with this.

Comment: What if you move it up inside the ui:define ? Also I'd put appendTo="@(body)" on it

Comment: It worked. thanks a lot